# Trouble getting a specific version of Jekyll - Windows

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-theme

How do I switch my version of Jekyll or download a specific version of it? This is all new to me and upon following the instructions provided by https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/
I was able to get the specific Ruby version I wanted with the RubyInstaller+DevKit but every time I use "gem install Jekyll bundler" it gives me only the most recent version of Jekyll. How would I proceed to get Jeyll version 3.8.2 for example?

I've tried to install a specifc version from the command line with gem install jekyll -v 3.8.2 and it installs but how do I switch versions now? I also tired using *3.8.2* serve --watch to switch versions but it just gives me:

*Configuration file: none
Source: C:/Users/Drey
Destination: C:/Users/Drey/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating...
jekyll 3.8.2 | Error:  Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Drey/NTUSER.DAT
Traceback (most recent call last):
23: from C:/Ruby27/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>' 22: from C:/Ruby27/bin/jekyll:23:in` load'
21: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>' 20: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in` program'
19: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go' 18: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in` execute'
17: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each' 16: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in` block in execute'
15: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program' 14: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in` start'
13: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each' 12: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in` block in start'
11: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process' 10: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in` build'
9: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site' 8: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in` process'
7: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:164:in `read' 6: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:16:in` read'
5: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:45:in `read_directories' 4: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:45:in` select'
3: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:46:in `block in read_directories' 2: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in` has_yaml_header?'
1: from C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in `open' C:/Ruby27/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.2/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in` initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Drey/NTUSER.DAT (Errno::EACCES)*

Answer (score 1):

So to install [Jekyll v3.8.2](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases/tag/v3.8.2) on Windows, definitely use `Ruby 2.7` which looks like you have installed.

Since you already have a project, run:

```
gem install jekyll -v 3.8.2
```

Now open the `Gemfile` and update the line

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.2"
```

It should look like this on a fresh install:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.2"
```

Next is installing everything, using `bundler install`. If that works correctly, then its time to check if its working.

```
bundle exec jekyll --version
>> jekyll 3.8.2
```

You can also try running `gem add webrick` if things aren't working still.
I had issues with `kramdown` as well, so make sure that is at `1.14`